# Spring Security : configuration error

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, xsd, spring-ide

I am not able to solve this problem that I have XSD version above 4 then why there is still conflict?

I am using Spring JARs and all of them  have version 4 or above and still getting error.

Following is XSD for `spring-security.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.1.xsd">
    <security:http auto-config="true">  <!-- ////this line holds error/////-->
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/"
            access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <security:form-login login-page="/login"
            default-target-url="/" authentication-failure-url="/loginerror" />
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
        <security:csrf disabled="true" />
    </security:http>
    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service>
                <security:user name="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"
                    password="admin" />
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
</beans>
```

and following is the error:

> Multiple annotations found at this line:
>     - Configuration problem: You cannot use a spring-security-2.0.xsd or spring-security-3.0.xsd schema with Spring Security 3.1. Please update
>   your schema declarations to the 3.1 schema. Offending resource: file
>   [C:/Documents and      Settings/Administrator/My Documents/Google
>   Drive/spring_workspace/spring
>   security_demo/WebContent/WEB-INF/security-context.xml]
>     - You cannot use a spring-security-2.0.xsd or spring-security-3.0.xsd schema with Spring Security 3.1. Please update your schema
>   declarations to the 3.1 schema.

**and this is my schema for dispatcher servlet:**

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">
```

First I thought I have conflicts in my both mentioned `.xsd` files but now both ' .xsd' files have same schema.

**Edit: Event details**

> org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException:
>   Configuration problem: You cannot use a spring-security-2.0.xsd or
>   spring-security-3.0.xsd schema with Spring Security 3.1. Please update
>   your schema declarations to the 3.1 schema. Offending resource: file
>   [C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/My Documents/Google
>   Drive/spring_workspace/spring
>   security_demo/WebContent/WEB-INF/security-context.xml]
>
> at
>   org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$BeansConfigProblemReporter.fatal(BeansConfig.java:1137)
>
> at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.fatal(ReaderContext.java:68)
>
> at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.fatal(ReaderContext.java:55)
>
> at
>   org.springframework.security.config.SecurityNamespaceHandler.parse(SecurityNamespaceHandler.java:66)
>
> at
>   org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.namespaces.DelegatingNamespaceHandlerResolver$ElementTrackingNamespaceHandler.parse(DelegatingNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:177)
>
> at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1411)
>
> at
>   org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$ErrorSuppressingBeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeansConfig.java:1428)
>
> at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1401)
>
> at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:172)
>
> at
>   org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$ToolingFriendlyBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(BeansConfig.java:1357)
>
> at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:94)
>
> at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
>
> at
>   org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$2.registerBeanDefinitions(BeansConfig.java:410)

How to solve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your exception says

> You should not use 4.1 xsd,since your spring security version is 3.1

In below line you have mentioned spring security version as 4.1,it should be 3.1

```
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.1.xsd">
```

Two ways to solve

1. Change to `http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd`
2. Remove version so that spring will take automatically `http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd`

**Update :** Add use-expressions attribute to `http`.Since you are using expression `hasRole('Role_Admin')` you have to provide this.

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
```

Comment: stll leading me to same `MatcherType` I am using eclipse `neon` if that is causing problem ?

Comment: No..make sure you have  `spring-security-web-3.1.X.RELEASE.jar from your classpath`..can you paste entire stacktrace..update the question

Comment: @HelloWorld change your url to `/**` ` in <security:intercept-url pattern="/**"/>`

Comment: actually when I tried in mars its working but not in eclipse `neon`

Comment: `neon` is creating `error log` in `.metadata` and I think I should jump back to `mars` until a stable `build` comes out and Thanks for your time too.

Comment: and it is causing error in every possible `configuration` file

Comment: @dur I think you are right in other IDE `sts` is not installed

Comment: @dur its still getting me `Internal Error` after removing `STS` and now I'm moving to `eclipse mars` :)